# Получил скиншот экрана но теперь программа как вирус WTF?

Tags: c#

Через код снизу получаем скриншот экрана но из за этого кода, когда прискачивании с **браузер Chrome ругается что это вредоносная программа**.
**Можно как то исправить?.**

```
                Bitmap screen;

                //в начале, нам надо получить размеры экрана.
                Rectangle screenDimensions = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
                Size s = new Size(screenDimensions.Width, screenDimensions.Height);

                //и создать соответствующее пустое изображение.
                screen = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height);
                Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(screen);

                //вуаля! делаем скриншот.
                memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, s);

                //и сохраняем в файл.
                screen.Save(file_store, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: А антивирусы что говорят? Тот же вирустотал?

Comment: Антивирус чист.Вирустотал тоже чист

Comment: Ну и игнорируйте хром, не вижу проблемы.

Comment: Но этот файл качают.Много людей и они жалуются что не скачалось.Им приходится переходить в загрузки в браузере и сохранить даже если вредоносный файл нажать ...

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/3258249 - вот это читали? Нет там помощи в вашем случае? Потому как не сталкивался, да и в чем проблема, все равно не вижу - кто угодно и на что угодно нынче ругается.

Comment: Я тоже немогу понять.Может вы знаете другой способ получить скриншот экрана?.

Comment: Слушайте, антивирусы ничего не нашли, а значит копать надо в сторону сайта или хрома.

Comment: Любая операция ввода вывода, а также перехват клавиатуры, мыши, захват изображения экрана рассматривается как потенциально-вредоносное действие. Некоторые программы/сервисы/антивирусы страдают паранойей больше чем другие их аналоги. Это факт - смиритесь с ним, ваш код здесь ни при чем. Gmail например, даже не проверяет опасность бинарного файла, а просто не принимает его в качестве вложения и все, даже в архиве, ну разве что под паролем, но я не пробовал..